# How to make the websocket server be at a router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm writing a websocket server using nodejs-ws module, but the server can only be at the root of the server, so how I can make it at a child router like localhost:3000/chat?

I need your help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example:

```
var ws = require('ws');
var http = require('http');

var httpServer = http.createServer();
httpServer.listen(3000, 'localhost');

var ws1 = new ws.Server({server:httpServer, path:"/chat"});
ws1.on('connection', function(){
  console.log("connection on /chat");
});

var ws2 = new ws.Server({server:httpServer, path:"/notifications"});
ws2.on('connection', function(){
  console.log("connection on /notifications");
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, and could you please tell me how to use this in express?

Answer (score 0):

> could you please tell me how to use this in express?

To route websockets with Express I'd rather use [express-ws-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws-routes)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express-ws-routes')();

app.websocket('/myurl', function(info, cb, next) {
    console.log(
        'ws req from %s using origin %s',
        info.req.originalUrl || info.req.url,
        info.origin
    );

    cb(function(socket) {
        socket.send('connected!');
    });
});
```